# url rewrite for SEO in opencart on localhost not working (or how to install wamp on windows 8 pc)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis

I'm trying to get seo url rewriting working in opencart 2.0.1.1 on my local computer but this seems to be a real pain. Yes, the option for SEO is checked at my server options in my backend and yes I have changed the .htaccess.txt file to .htaccess

I'm working on my laptop with windows 8.1 and use IIS7. IIS7 works only with web.config instead of .htaccess which is used for url rewriting by opencart.

So at first I tried to install wamp, because it contains the required apache rewrite module. But for some reason I can not start wamp. I installed wamp on port 8080 or 8888 instead of 80 to avoid conflicts with IIS, I even stopped the IIS sever but no success. Normally they should be able to work together. If anyone has a guideline for installing wamp together with IIS on windows 8 computer, I would be very glad. I tried several things on the internet without success. At this moment I use IIS fastcgi to get both my asp websites and my php files running on my localhost.

Secondly, I tried to install ISAPI-rewrite 3 Lite which is free. It seem to recognize the .htaccess file but when I try to click on a product with a seo text defined, I get error 404. Offcourse also the related category of the product is seo defined. Is ISAPI-rewrite completely compatible with apache rewrite?

As a third step I tried to reconvert the .htacces file for apache to a web.config file for IIS, but I get the message that IIS can not translate the "RewriteBase /" rule. Can I solve this?

So I'm stuck with all options I had in mind. I would be happy if any of the 3 options would work. So any help or reference to a good tutorial would be very appreciated.

And in case I would get option 3 (with a web.config file) running, do I always have to reconvert from .htacces to web.config in case I would buy one of the SEO extensions later?

SabKo

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. I was able to install wamp server on windows 8.
My error was related to a conflict on the port used for Mysql (port 3306). I got the message that "wampmysld64 was stopped". But I had already installed a Mysql server before for other applications. I changed the port for wampmysqld64 from 3306 to 3308 and everything is working now.

SabKo